# How to reset a variable just before entering a function?

Tags: variables, functions

I am facing a problem where the if condition in the function `waterNowrun` is able to execute once after the program starts as the variable `v` is 0 at the start, but upon starting it again the if does not execute as `v` is not <10.

After some debugging I had decided that `v` would have to be reset before entering the function, and so I set `v` to 0 in the loop, then what happened is that the if was always satisfied and did not go to the else.

Is it possible to do it? Maybe with interrupts or something else?

Hardware-ESP8266 based NodeMCU

**In conclusion-**

I want a reset a variable `v` once just before the function `waterNowrun` starts, how do I do it?

**My code-**

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <BlynkSimpleEsp8266.h>
#include <NTPClient.h>
#include <WiFiUdp.h>
#include "DHT.h"
#include "LiquidCrystal_PCF8574.h"

#define BLYNK_PRINT Serial
#define DHT_PIN_DATA  12
// LCD definations
#define LCD_ADDRESS 0x27
#define LCD_ROWS 2
#define LCD_COLUMNS 16
#define SCROLL_DELAY 150
#define BACKLIGHT 25
#define DHTTYPE DHT22

// You should get Auth Token in the Blynk App.
// Go to the Project Settings (nut icon).
char auth[] = "ymri80lFL9_xZhf6WIRHtQ1qadfafdEWOt9zBy";
char ssid[] = "-Hotspot-82DB";
char pass[] = "b35288qqafdd";
int autoSch;
int waterNow;
int morTime;
int afterTime;
int postNoon;
int eveTime;
int schTime;
int minStep;
int interval;
int count;
int flag = 0;
int soilHum = A0;
int v;
unsigned long previousMillis = 0;

DHT dht(DHT_PIN_DATA, DHTTYPE);
LiquidCrystal_PCF8574 lcdI2C;
WiFiUDP ntpUDP;
NTPClient timeClient(ntpUDP, "in.pool.ntp.org", 19800, 600000);
// This function will be called every time Slider Widget
// in Blynk app writes values to the Virtual Pin 1

BLYNK_CONNECTED() {
  Blynk.syncAll();
}

BLYNK_WRITE(V0)
{
  autoSch = param.asInt(); // assigning incoming value from pin V1 to a variable
}

BLYNK_WRITE(V1)
{
  morTime = param.asInt(); // assigning incoming value from pin V1 to a variable
}

BLYNK_WRITE(V2)
{
  afterTime = param.asInt(); // assigning incoming value from pin V1 to a variable
}

BLYNK_WRITE(V6)
{
  postNoon = param.asInt(); // assigning incoming value from pin V1 to a variable
}

BLYNK_WRITE(V3)
{
  eveTime = param.asInt(); // assigning incoming value from pin V1 to a variable
}

BLYNK_WRITE(V10)
{
  waterNow = param.asInt(); // assigning incoming value from pin V1 to a variable
Serial.println("Boo BOO is BOO BOO billa");
}

BLYNK_WRITE(V4)
{
  schTime = param.asInt(); // assigning incoming value from pin V1 to a variable
}

BLYNK_WRITE(V7)
{
  minStep = param.asInt(); // assigning incoming value from pin V1 to a variable
}

void setup()
{
  dht.begin();
  lcdI2C.begin(LCD_COLUMNS, LCD_ROWS, LCD_ADDRESS, BACKLIGHT);
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
  pinMode(14, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(14, LOW);
  Blynk.virtualWrite(V5, 0);
  Blynk.virtualWrite(V8, 0);
  pinMode(0, INPUT_PULLUP);
  Serial.begin(9600);

  //WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  Blynk.begin(auth, ssid, pass);
  while ( WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED ) {
    delay ( 500 );
    Serial.print ( "." );
  }
  timeClient.begin();
  Blynk.syncAll();
}

void loop()
{
  Blynk.run();
  time_run();
  lcd();
  butPress();

  timeClient.update();
  if (waterNow != 1) {
    Blynk.virtualWrite(V10, 0);
   // digitalWrite(14, LOW);
    Blynk.virtualWrite(V5, 0);
    Blynk.virtualWrite(V8, minStep * 60);

    Blynk.syncAll();
  }
  if (waterNow == 1) {
    waterNowrun(v = 0);

  } else if (autoSch == 0) {
    auto_run1();
  } else if (autoSch == 1) {
    sch_run2();
  } else {
    Blynk.virtualWrite(V10, 0);
    digitalWrite(14, LOW);
    Blynk.virtualWrite(V5, 0);
    Blynk.syncAll();
  }
  Blynk.syncAll();
  Serial.println(timeClient.getFormattedTime());
  Serial.println(analogRead(A0));
}
void butPress() {
  if (digitalRead(0) == LOW) {
    if (flag == 0) {


      digitalWrite(14, HIGH);
      delay(3000);
      digitalWrite(14, LOW);

      flag = 1;
    }
    else {
      digitalWrite(14, LOW);
      flag = 0;
    }
  }
}

void test() {
  if (v < 10) {
    digitalWrite(14, HIGH);
    v++;
    delay(500);


  } else {
    digitalWrite(14, LOW);

  }

}


void lcd() {
  //lcdI2C.clear();
  lcdI2C.setCursor(0, 0);
  timeClient.update();
  lcdI2C.print(timeClient.getFormattedTime());

  if (autoSch == 0) {
    lcdI2C.setCursor(9, 0);
    lcdI2C.print("Auto     ");
  } else {
    lcdI2C.print(" Sch   ");
  }


  if (digitalRead(14) == 1) {
    lcdI2C.selectLine(2);
    lcdI2C.print("Wtr Now           ");
  }
  else
  {

    if (int(timeClient.getHours()) < 6 && morTime == 1 && autoSch == 0) {
      Blynk.syncAll();
      lcdI2C.selectLine(2);
      lcdI2C.print("Auto Wtr at: 6a ");
    } else if (int(timeClient.getHours()) < 12 && afterTime == 1 && autoSch == 0) {
      Blynk.syncAll();
      lcdI2C.selectLine(2);
      lcdI2C.print("Auto Wtr at: 12n ");
    } else if (int(timeClient.getHours()) < 14 && postNoon == 1 && autoSch == 0) {
      Blynk.syncAll();
      lcdI2C.selectLine(2);
      lcdI2C.print("Auto Wtr at:14pn ");
    } else if (int(timeClient.getHours()) < 18 && eveTime == 1 && autoSch == 0) {
      Blynk.syncAll();
      lcdI2C.selectLine(2);
      lcdI2C.print("Auto Wtr at: 18e ");
    } else if (int(timeClient.getHours()) >= 18 && morTime == 1 && autoSch == 0) {
      Blynk.syncAll();
      lcdI2C.selectLine(2);
      lcdI2C.print("Auto Wtr at: 6a ");
    } else {
      lcdI2C.selectLine(2);
      lcdI2C.print("My name is billa");
    }

  }

}

void waterNowrun(int v) {
  /*
    Serial.println (currentMillis);
    Serial.println (previousMillis);
    Serial.println(interval);
  */


  if (v < 10) {

    Serial.println("Boo Boo");

    digitalWrite(14, HIGH);
    Blynk.virtualWrite(V5, 255);
    lcdI2C.selectLine(2);
    lcdI2C.print("Wtr Now :");
    /*
      lcdI2C.print((minStep * 60) - ((currentMillis - previousMillis) / 1000));
      Blynk.virtualWrite(V8, ((interval / 1000) - ((currentMillis - previousMillis) / 1000)));
    */
    Blynk.syncAll();
    delay(500);
    v++;
  } else {
    Blynk.virtualWrite(V10, 0);
    digitalWrite(14, LOW);
    Blynk.virtualWrite(V5, 0);
    Blynk.virtualWrite(V8, 0);

    Blynk.syncAll();


  }
}

void sch_run2() {
  if (schTime == 1) {
    digitalWrite(14, HIGH);
    Blynk.virtualWrite(V5, 255);
    Blynk.syncAll();
  } else if (schTime == 0) {
    digitalWrite(14, LOW);
    Blynk.virtualWrite(V5, 0);
    Blynk.syncAll();
  }

}

void time_run() {
  Blynk.virtualWrite(V11, int(timeClient.getHours()));
  Blynk.virtualWrite(V12, int(timeClient.getMinutes()));
  Blynk.virtualWrite(V13, float(dht.readTempC()));
  Blynk.virtualWrite(V14, float(dht.readHumidity()));

}





void auto_run1() {
  if (morTime == 1 && String(timeClient.getFormattedTime()) > "06:00:00" && String(timeClient.getFormattedTime()) < "06:20:00") {
    digitalWrite(14, HIGH);
    Blynk.virtualWrite(V5, 255);
    Blynk.syncAll();
  }
  else if (afterTime == 1 && String(timeClient.getFormattedTime()) > "12:00:00" && String(timeClient.getFormattedTime()) < "12:20:00") {
    digitalWrite(14, HIGH);
    Blynk.virtualWrite(V5, 255);
    Blynk.syncAll();
  }
  else if (postNoon == 1 && String(timeClient.getFormattedTime()) > "14:00:00" && String(timeClient.getFormattedTime()) < "14:20:00") {
    digitalWrite(14, HIGH);
    Blynk.virtualWrite(V5, 255);
    Blynk.syncAll();
  }
  else if (eveTime == 1 && String(timeClient.getFormattedTime()) > "12:59:00" && String(timeClient.getFormattedTime()) < "13:01:00") {
    digitalWrite(14, HIGH);
    Blynk.virtualWrite(V5, 255);
    Blynk.syncAll();
  }
  else  {
    //(String(timeClient.getFormattedTime() == "06:20:00" || "12:20:00" || "14:20:00" || "13:48:00"))
    //waterNowrun();
    /*
      Blynk.virtualWrite(V10, 0);
      digitalWrite(14, LOW);
      Blynk.virtualWrite(V5, 0);
      Blynk.virtualWrite(V8, 0);
      Blynk.syncAll();
    */
  }
}
```

Comment: The logic behind your explanation is not entirely clear to me, but the variable `int v` inside the `waternowRun` function is a local variable that is only valid inside this function and *not the same* as the "global" variable `int v`. This probably causes the confusion. If you want to retain the value of a local variable between function calls, you could declare it as a `static` variable but that might or might not be what you want. This is also a programming question and not an Arduino specific question.

Comment: And this is exacly why it's discouraged to use global variables... Anyway, `test()` function changes global variable `v` (great name if you wanted to encrypt the code). The `waterNowrun(int v)` changes local variable conveniently named `v` that shadows global `v`... take a pick what's messing it up

Comment: @StarCat Can you please explain how static variables work?

Comment: If's explained quite clearly here: [https://www.tutorialspoint.com/what-is-the-lifetime-of-a-static-variable-in-a-cplusplus-function](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/what-is-the-lifetime-of-a-static-variable-in-a-cplusplus-function). If you declare a variable static inside of a function (for example `static int counter;`, it will keep its value when the function is called multiple times, as in the example from the link. Normally a local variable is re-allocated (reset) when leaving a function and re-entering it.

Comment: @StarCat I tried it does not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The purpose of the waterNowrun function and 'v' seems to be to turn on some water and keep it running for 10 iterations, before turning it off?

I would split the waterNowrun into two functions:

```
void waterOn() {
    Serial.println("Boo Boo");
    digitalWrite(14, HIGH);
    Blynk.virtualWrite(V5, 255);
    lcdI2C.selectLine(2);
    lcdI2C.print("Wtr Now :");
    /*
      lcdI2C.print((minStep * 60) - ((currentMillis - previousMillis) / 1000));
      Blynk.virtualWrite(V8, ((interval / 1000) - ((currentMillis -     previousMillis) / 1000)));
    */
    Blynk.syncAll();
    delay(500);
}

void waterOff() {
    Blynk.virtualWrite(V10, 0);
    digitalWrite(14, LOW);
    Blynk.virtualWrite(V5, 0);
    Blynk.virtualWrite(V8, 0);
    Blynk.syncAll();
}
```

In the loop() I would do

```
...
if (waterNow != 1) {
    waterOff();
}
if (waterNow == 1) {
    if (v < 10) {
        waterOn();
        v++;
    }
    else {
        waterOff();
        v = 0;
    }
} else if (autoSch == 0) {
    auto_run1();
} else if (autoSch == 1) {
    sch_run2();
} else {
    waterOff();
}
...
```

But do yourself a favour and rename v to waterPeriod or something that is easier to remember.

Comment: Appreciate the help...  Just for clarification I'll try to explain what I've understood- So if waterNow is 1 and v<10 then waterOn until v> or = 10, go to the else statement and do WaterOff which also turns waterNow to 0 hence exiting the if statement and setting v=0, to reset the state of the variable.                              Is that what I am supposed to understand?

Comment: Hi, sorry for not getting back to you before. Yes, that's right. When you start out, waterNow is false (or 0) and v is 0. When waterOn is true (or 1), we get to the waterNow==1 branch. v is 0, so < 10, the water is turned on and v is incremented. For the next iterations, we do the same, until v reaches 10. Then we go to the else branch, turns off the water and resets V. Now waterNow and v are 0 like when we  started.

Comment: If going through waterOn again and again is a problem, you can try
    if (v == 0) {
      waterOn();
   }
   if (v++ == 10) {
     waterOff();
      v = 0;
   }

EDIT: Seems like comments are formatted. Linebreaks after branckets and ;

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear what behavior you expect from `v`, especially since you have two of them - the global `v` at the head of your program, and the parameter `v` of the function `waterNowrun(int v)`.

My understanding of what you want is that the function should maintain control of `v`. If so,

- Get rid of the global `v`';
- In `loop()`, don't pass anything to `waterNowrun()`
- Inside `waterNowrun()` declare `static int v = 0;`. That initialization to zero will only happen once, before the program starts (not on every entry to the function, even though it kind of reads like that). From then on, only your `waterNowrun()` function can change `v`.

That may not be the only logic change you need to make - I don't understand what you're trying to do with `v` and can't critique that. But at least now `v` will be entirely controlled from within the function, and it will not change between invocations of the function.

Some background: A static variable declared within a function is like a global in that it has a fixed memory address for the entire program run; unlike a local (including a function parameter) that gets reallocated in memory each time the function is entered (and therefore must be initialized on every entry). But *unlike* a global, it is invisible - not known about - anywhere outside of that function.

Comment: Unfortunately this answer does not solve the problem as I am facing the same issue as before where the function works one time but not a second

Comment: Please clarify what it is you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I'm trying to turn on watering for a particular number of iterations and then turn it off, the problem is that the iterations counter ```v``` remains = or > 10 hence not entering the function  a second time

Comment: Try to add a "v = 0;" line after the two other waterOff(); calls.

Comment: You need to reset the counter when you turn off the water and increase it while the water is on.